# Cannot link with mysql-connector

Tags: c++, mysql

I am using visual studio code while write C++. I want to connect to MySQL database on localhost in C++. I installed MySQL Connector from mysql.com.
Is there an error in these two lines? Since the include and lib directory are in program files, I started the editor as administrator, still didn't work

main.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
using namespace std;

//for demonstration only. never save your password in the code!
const string server = "localhost:3307";
const string username = "";
const string password = "";

int main()
{
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt;

    try
    {
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect(server, username, password);
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException e)
    {
        cout << "Could not connect to server. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe etkin dosyayı derle",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-IC:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/",
                "-LC:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/lib -lmysqlcppconn",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Hata Ayıklayıcısı tarafından oluşturulan görev."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Error:

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g '-IC:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/' '-LC:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/lib -lmysqlcppconn' c:\Users\yagizgil\Desktop\scripts\mrns\main.cpp -o c:\Users\yagizgil\Desktop\scripts\mrns\main.exe 

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\yagizgil\AppData\Local\Temp\ccfxSMfR.o: in function `check_lib':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:82: undefined reference to `check(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:83: undefined reference to `check(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\yagizgil\AppData\Local\Temp\ccfxSMfR.o: in function `get_driver_instance_by_name':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:95: undefined reference to `_get_driver_instance_by_name'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

it gives this error before entering any database name. I try everyhing

Comment: This doesn't seem like an error in the code. You have *link errors* which means you are building the application wrongly, and what you need to change is tasks.json. Unfortunately I don't know much about mysql. Read the documentation **carefully** and do what it says.

Comment: `"-LC:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/lib -lmysqlcppconn"` needs to be two separate arguments not one, it'll be setting `C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/lib -lmysqlcppconn` as a link directory which isn't what you want